# Weird bug while passing double pointers to a function in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, undefined-behavior, dereference

Bug:

While passing a double pointer to a function the value of the fields that the pointer is pointing to seems to be dependent on some local variable of the function.

More specifically when I comment the line L(in the function "function")
Output:

```
In the main function: 1
In the function: 1
```

But when I uncomment the same line,

Output:

```
In the main function: 1
In the function: 0
```

program:

```c
typedef struct s{
    int *value; 
}s;


s** initialize()
{
    s** temp = (s**)malloc(sizeof(s*));
    s* f = (s*)malloc(sizeof(s));
    f->value = NULL;
    temp = &f;
    return temp;
}

void function(s** what)
{

//Line L:   size_t count = 0;
    printf("In the function: %d\n", (*what)->value == NULL);
}

int main()
{
    s** m = initialize();
    printf("In the main function: %d\n", (*m)->value == NULL);
    function(m);
}
```

What I have tried:

- I thought that I am getting random outputs, but that was not the case as I am consistently getting the same output.
- I tried deciphering the assembly language code but that was too cryptic for me.

Environment:

- compiler: `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`
- operating system: linux mint

Comment: `temp = &f;` -> `*temp = f:`

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: @SouravGhosh RobertS has made a very good statement regarding this, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62351067/12139179

Comment: @Ctx that answer belongs on meta

Comment: @AndrasDeak I disagree, it belongs exactly there where it can be read, when this issue is brought up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `initialize`

```
s** initialize()
{
    s** temp = (s**)malloc(sizeof(s*));
    s* f = (s*)malloc(sizeof(s));
    f->value = NULL;
    temp = &f;
    return temp;
}
```

can invoke undefined behavior because it returns pointer to a local variable. And moreover it has a memory leak.

At first a memory was allocated and its address was assigned to the variable temp

```
    s** temp = (s**)malloc(sizeof(s*));
```

Then the pointer was reassigned

```
    temp = &f;
```

So the allocated memory is not freed.

The pointer is assigned by the address of a local variable

```
    s* f = (s*)malloc(sizeof(s));
    //...
    temp = &f;
```

After exiting the function the variable `f` will not alive. So the pointer temp has an invalid value.

It seems what you mean is the following

```
s** initialize()
{
    s** temp = (s**)malloc(sizeof(s*));
    s* f = (s*)malloc(sizeof(s));
    f->value = NULL;
    *temp = f;
    return temp;
}
```

If to make the changes you will get the expected result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s{
    int *value; 
}s;

s** initialize()
{
    s** temp = (s**)malloc(sizeof(s*));
    s* f = (s*)malloc(sizeof(s));
    f->value = NULL;
    *temp = f;
    return temp;
}

void function(s** what)
{

//Line L:   size_t count = 0;
    printf("In the function: %d\n", (*what)->value == NULL);
}

int main( void )
{
    s** m = initialize();
    printf("In the main function: %d\n", (*m)->value == NULL);
    function(m);

    free( *m );
    free( m );
}
```

The program output is

```
In the main function: 1
In the function: 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
s** initialize()
{
    s** temp = (s**)malloc(sizeof(s*));
    s* f = (s*)malloc(sizeof(s));
    f->value = NULL;
    temp = &f;          // temp is now the address of a local variable
    return temp;        // now temp is returned
                        // that's undefined behavior when the returned
                        // pointer is used
}
```

The variable `f` doesn't exist when the `initialize` function returns, so you are returning the address of a non-existing variable. Using the address will be undefined behavior, i.e. anything can happen and there is no way in general to explain it.

On a specific system, we can do some guessing. My guess is that once you add the line with a new variable, it overwrites the memory location where `f` used to be stored. Without the new variable the location where `f` used to be stored is still the same.

Comment: Argh -- you beat me to it by like a minute.